# pandas timedelta and filtering negative values

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have a pandas dataframe with column time_taken as a timedelta64[ns].  Here's a example of the values :

```
idle_time["time_taken"]

0                   NaT
1       00:01:41.648602
2       00:01:40.224034
3       00:01:44.029010
4       00:01:35.649479
              ...      
11608   00:33:18.597127
11609   00:03:09.414821
11610   00:04:43.362200
11611   00:25:36.113369
11612   00:06:27.766094
Name: time_taken, Length: 11613, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

I want to filter for negative values,  i know there is one because running the statement idle_time["time_taken"].min() shows a negative.  However i want to filter all rows with a negative.

I've tried `idle_time[idle_time["time_taken"] > 0]`but it shows

> Invalid comparison between dtype=timedelta64[ns] and int

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Convert timedeltas to some numbers, e.g. by [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html):

```
idle_time[idle_time["time_taken"].dt.total_seconds() > 0]
```

Or compare by `Timedelta`:

```
idle_time[idle_time["time_taken"] > pd.Timedelta(0)]
```